# How can you jump further in Temple Run?

Tags: temple-run

I'm playing *Temple Run* for iOS and there are parts where you need to jump really far in order to get over a broken path.

Does anyone know how to jump over these tricky parts? Is there a way to jump higher or further? Is there some other way to survive?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @tutuDajuju! Could you possibly take a screenshot of one of the areas/tricky parts you mean? It'll make it easier for people to help you. :)

Comment: The only cases I know where gaps are longer than a jump's distance are gaps which require you to stick to the narrow footing on either side, so instead of jumping, just tilt to the left/right

Comment: [at]FallenAngelEyes - I'll try to capture a screenshot if it happens again..
@JohnoBoy - I swear the leap is without narrow sides

so neither of you have ever seen something like that?

Comment: yeah it happens to me too!! There are no narrow areas to run on it just seems too far to jump....sure there isnt another button or combination to push in order to jump farther?

Comment: +1 for timing. Also make sure you haven't just tripped. If your speed has slowed down, you may not make the longer jumps

Comment: @AaarghZombies `@TimmyJim What's the reason behind the "farther" → "further" edit? From my understanding, the usage of "farther" was correct in this context. AFAIK, "farther" is typically used to refer to physical distances, while "further" is more commonly used for figurative distances. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farther

Comment: @TimmyJim, further is the more common term in common speech when dealing with a comparative distance when no original unit is specified: "To reach further"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's more of a timing issue. The farther you go the farther some of the jumps get and you have to hit it at the absolute last step before you fall and you'll barely land it. To answer the original question though, there isn't any way to jump higher.

Comment: It also seems that speed is a crucial factor. The faster you go the easier it is to make those long jumps.

Comment: Yes, upgrades allow you to run faster if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

You needs speed. If you tripped and your speed is too slow, you will fall and drown.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try maybe getting a resurrection boost (wings).  Then, when you get to that part, you can just activate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go really far and really fast then you can start to jump faster and farther

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug. I too encountered a very very long beoken path. I wasnat a good speed but wasnt aboe to. Later i got the info it s happening because of a bug issues. Upgrade to fix the issue.

Comment: Where did you get this 'info' that it's happening because of a bug? Can you link to it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue - it is definitely a matter of timing.

Make sure to jump at the VERY last second.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Just so you know, we do things a little differently than other forums, so we have a few extra rules. One of these is that you shouldn't post answers if they've already been said. It seems like the above answers already give the answer you are trying to say in this post.